# Creating a list of files contained in a buffer

Tags: external-command, filesystem

Let's say I have the following buffer:

```
foo.txt
bar buzz.txt
fizz/foo.txt
fizz/fuzz/fozz.txt
```

Representing an arborescence that I need to create.

How can I easily create it from Vim?  I.e. How can I visually select the list of
files and execute a function which would create the directories and files in the
current folder?

Comment: vim can invoke external cmd, so it can be done with/in vim for sure. However I don't think vim is the best way to do it.  I would do it in shell way.

Comment: @Kent: I would tend to agree with you, that's not what Vim was designed to do (maybe it would be a job for emacs), I was just curious of an efficient way to do it, you know something like a challenge maybe :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can take advantage of the way vim execute command when applied over a range.

Select your lines and do:

```
:'<,'>call system('mkdir -p '. fnamemodify(fnameescape(getline('.')),':h:p').' && touch '.fnamemodify(fnameescape(getline('.')),':p'))
```

This will apply the command

```
call system(...)
```

over **every line** you've selected.

The command is calling two external tools, `mkdir` and `touch` (you may change this if you work in windows).

- `mkdir -p` will create the directory (and subdirectories if necessary).
  The argument is the escaped current line modified to show only the folder path (not the filename)
- `touch` will create the file
  The argument is the escaped current line modified to show the path and the filename

You need to add the `shellescape` function so that the filename is correctly escaped for the system call.

The `fnamemodify` is handy if you want to modify the filename and path.

---

**Note:**

Alternatively to `shellescape`, you can use one of the following:

- the `:S` modifier in `fnamemodify`
- enclose the string with double quotes `"` (thanks @Tommy\ A for the suggestion)

---

See:

- `:h v_:`
- `:h system`
- `:h getline()`
- `:h shellescape()`
- `:h fnamemodify()`
- `:h ::S`

Comment: Adding double quotes around the path names should make it safe enough without `shellescape()`.

Answer (score 4):

If you must do it with Vim:

```
function! Touch() range abort                       
    for fn in getline(a:firstline, a:lastline)
        if !filereadable(fn)
            let base = fnamemodify(fn, ':h')
            if !isdirectory(base)
                call mkdir(base, 'p')
            endif 
            call writefile([], fn, 'a')
        endif     
    endfor        
endfunction       

command! -range Touch <line1>,<line2>call Touch()
```

Beware that this doesn't try to be the most efficient, and only does minimal error checking.

Same thing with a shell script:

```
#! /bin/sh                                            
while IFS= read -r FN; do
    mkdir -p "$(dirname "$FN")" && touch "$FN" || exit 1
done
```

You can pipe the relevant range of lines to it.